# Security in Zuul Gateway

Tags: spring, microservices, netflix-zuul

I am trying to set up a gateway server for microservices  using Zuul.

I have created an authorization server to issue tokens.Should I validate the token in the gateway server using ZuulFilter for each request  or let each service
validate and parse the tokens.What will be the best way to implement it.or  Is there any other way ? Any Suggestion/Solutions will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, it should be the `gateway` that should interact with the `authorization` server and decide whether the underlying `services` should be allowed access.